# How set DocumentRoot to a subfolder on a subdomain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have the follow structure:

/var/www/subdomain.domain.com/app1/public/index.php
/var/www/subdomain.domain.com/app2/public/index.php

To get to the app just type:

www.subdomain.domain.com/app1/public

But, there's someway to keep like

www.subdomain.domain.com/app1 and www.subdomain.domain.com/app2?

Without the /public, but, still redirecting to that subfolder, because I need the index.php?

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to provide a proper answer without knowing what you've tried.

Comment: IMO, the best way to set this up (and I've done it before), is to use apache's `mod_vhost_alias` and the `VirtualDocumentRoot` directive which allows you to use the domain name to map the document root to a folder. It's actually pretty simple to use if you have done any configuration with apache before. I had it setup so `[anything].mydomain.com` would map to `/var/www/[anything]/` with a wildcard dns pretty easily. Then creating a subdomain was as simple as creating a folder under `/var/www/`

Comment: Nevermind what I said. When you are saying "subdomain", that is not what you mean. What you are talking about is simply mapping a folder to another. You can do like Mads said and alias the folders or use mod_rewrite to map the URI. Both would do the same thing. What I was talking about would map like `app1.domain.com` to a different document root specific to just app1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Location "/app1">
    Alias "/app1/public"
</Location>

<Location "/app2">
    Alias "/app2/public"
</Location>
```

Comment: You mean like this on my .conf file?
`Alias /app1/ "/var/www/subdomain.domain.com.br/app1/public/"
<Directory /var/www/subdomain.domain.com.br>`
...